# Trigger function on enter in angular input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

is there a way to trigger event when clicking on ENTER key in the input field?
I found a directive that someone suggested to use, but I wonder if there is a simple way to do it.

I am using angular 1.3.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
 $timeout(function() {
     angular.element('#myselector').trigger('click');
  }, 100);
```

If you want trigger on press on `enter` key you need to write like that

```
<input ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? myFunc() : null">
```

Comment: This will recognize every click, I meant that I want to recognize only ENTER.

Comment: This dose not work in firefox

Comment: Saved my life ! Thanks.

Comment: For new versions of angular you can use: (keyup.enter)="someFunction()"